# What are some strategies to implement search functionality to filter out data in an application (Frontend)?

Tags: rest, design-patterns

I've built a RESTful API that fetches employees from the database, Now I want to implement search functionality that filters employees by name and then fetches it. In the frontend, I've fetched employees and then based on user input I'm converting both user input and result from db to lowercase and then matching for similarity? Do you think this problem can be approached in a different way? any other strategies? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, let the database do the comparison for you in SQL. Less resources will be used throughout the entire stack. One of the main features for databases is searching for specific data. Also SQL is case insensitive so no need to do a toLowerCase.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE name LIKE '%SearchValue%'
```

Only select the columns you need.